# Query Optimization, Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012;

I am using a query to find deltas in a table. 
I have an archive table that has all the records with Licenceno PK,FileID

I want to find out how many Licenceno are in a fileId but are not in previous FileID.

Code Used:

```
Select count(*) from table where fileid = 123 and Licenceno not in (select Licenceno from table where fileid <123)
```

The code works fine but the problem is some of the fileIds have the same number of records as the previous ones but take 4 hours and are still running..

1. Is it a table issue?
2. Index cant be an issue as the whole table has
       a non clustered index.
3. It is happening generally when i am calculating deltas for the latest Licenceno.
4. or Query planning is the issue?

I am not able to solve this for the past 5 days.

Comment: Are you able to share the execution plan? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Could you change the Not in to Not Exists? Like this Select count(*) 
from table t1
where t1.fileid = 123 
and t1.Licenceno not Exists 
(select 1 from table t2 where t2.fileid < t1.fileID) does that help?

Comment: I cannot share the execution plan, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `count(distinct)`?

```
select count(distinct licenseno)
from table
where fileid = 123;
```

For this query, you want an index on `(fileid, licenseno)`.

You are complicating the logic by thinking sequentially ("have I seen this `licenseno` already?").  Instead, you just want to count the distinct values.

EDIT:

For this problem, you can try two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select licenseno, min(fileid) as min_fileid
      from t
      where licenseno <= 123
      group by licenseno
     ) t
where min_fileid = 123;
```

How good the performance is relative to other approaches dependson how selective `<= 123` is.

Comment: This doesn't exclude Licenceno which exist in the table with a `fileid < 123`

Comment: this will calculate the distincts in that fileId not the whole table because of a where clause

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . That is a really good reason why that approach does not work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, can you tell me what is thought the process here and how did you come up with this, I got the result so quick I couldn't even blink, can you explain a bit how this is faster than my query? that would make my day.

Comment: @Rishi . . . `NOT IN` with a subquery is likely not to optimize well.  Your query might improve with `NOT EXISTS`.  In this case, though, the logic seems like aggregation logic, which is why I proposed the second solution (the first was based on my misunderstanding the question).

Comment: Any resource/Book to read, to understand this optimization stuff better, I really want to learn what are the best practices for query optimizations.

Comment: @Rishi . . . Optimization is a complicated subject.  You should start by learning "explain" and what query plans mean.  The documentation is a good place to start.  There are also many other resources for SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

I would rewrite your query to use an exists clause, and also add an appropriate index:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)(
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    fileid = 123 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.Licenseno = t1.Licenseno AND t2.fileid < 123);
```

An index on `(Licenseno, fileid)` might help here:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (Licenseno, fileid);
```

You may also try the came composite index in the reverse order:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (fileid, Licenseno);
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff It feels like driving the down road at night and someone telling me my headlights are off.

Comment: THe index should be (fileid, licenseno).

Comment: @PeterHe - it depends for what you are optimising. The `fileid = 123` would benefit from that way round but  if nested loops a seek on `t2.Licenseno = t1.Licenseno AND t2.fileid < 123` would need the reverse

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `LAG` for this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT fileid,
               LAG(fileid) OVER (PARTITION BY Licenceno ORDER BY fileid) AS prevFileID
        FROM   TABLE
        WHERE  fileid <= 123 ) D
WHERE  fileid = 123
       AND prevFileID IS NULL
```

... or an aggregation query ...

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Flag,
         FROM   TABLE
         WHERE  fileid <= 123         
         GROUP  BY Licenceno
         HAVING MIN(fileid) = 123 )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   T
```